# React native redirect for android

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react native android app . I create a user login component and want to redirect the page on home after user login but by my code not redirect to home page so any one help me to redirect page after user login.

```
let response = await fetch('mysite.com/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        user:{
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
        }
    })
});

let res = await response.text();
if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    this.redirect('home');
} else {
    let error = res;
    throw error;
}
```

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: why don't u use react native router flux

Answer (score 0):

if you use react native router flux you should be able to create different scenes like the routes on the web and redirect the user to different components within the app.

In more detail.

1) install the plugin and then create a router.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import ScarletScreen from './ScarletScreen';
import GrayScreen from './GrayScreen';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="scarlet"
          component={ScarletScreen}
          title="Scarlet"
          initial
        />
        <Scene
          key="gray"
          component={GrayScreen}
          title="Gray"
        />
      </Scene>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

2) import it on your app.js

```
import Router from './Router'
```

and use it inside the provider

```
<Provider>
   <Router />
</Provider>
```

3) now on your component if you import and call the scene you can navigate there

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

Actions.gray()
```

You can follow instructions also here > https://medium.com/differential/react-native-basics-using-react-native-router-flux-f11e5128aff9

Also documentation for further implementations like tabs etc https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux#documentation